# Jquery for one page site

Tags: jquery

I am using following jquery code for my one page portfolio
my site
http://www.hettzdesigns.com

but when page loads it directly goes to contact section of site instead of index section.

Can anyone tell where it is going wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('nav ul li a').click(function(){
        var el = $(this).attr('href');
        var elWrapped = $(el);
        scrollToDiv(elWrapped,140);
        return false;
    });

    function scrollToDiv(element,navheight){
        var offset = element.offset();
        var offsetTop = offset.top;
        var totalScroll = offsetTop-navheight;
        $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: totalScroll
        }, 650);
    }
});
```

Comment: Why are you loading two versions of jQuery?

Comment: first of all place your function scrollToDiv outside document ready

Answer (score 8):

It's because you're giving `autofocus` to your form fields which makes your fields automatically get focus when the page loads.